# MENU not showing up on mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, blogger

Dears, I have a problem with MENU on the blog that I'm working on. Everything is working perfectly on the laptop version of the blog but when I test it on my phone MENU doesn't show up (roll up) and there is no possibility to click on the menu. Could anyone tell me how to fix this?
Link to the website: http://wibracjezdrowia.blogspot.com/p/o-gabinecie.html
2nd MENU (GREEN MENU)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height for the nav id should be auto, don't give fixed size.

try this

css:

```
#nav {
height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add flot:left in .nav class in mobile version:

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```